# Android: check box checked and Disabled

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I want to select only one checkbox among 4 checkboxes. I mean, If one checkbox is selected others should be disabled. how to achieve this?

Comment: If you only ever want one `CheckBox` checked then it sounds like you really want to be using `RadioButtons`. [Check this out](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/).

Comment: @Asok But I want to try with checkbox!

Comment: Okay... Well then add `android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"` to your CheckBox's in xml, add `onCheckBoxClicked` method in your activity where you check if a `CheckBox` is checked and then for all other ones set `chkBox.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: @Asok this one correct?? `public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (v.getId()){
  case R.id.checkBox1:
   cb1.setEnabled(true);
   break;
  case R.id.checkBox2:
   cb2.setEnabled(false);
   break;
  }`

Comment: See edit below. I added `if` statements that should help you along. I haven't tested, but a little tweaking, if necessary may get you what you're looking for.

Comment: @Asok Thanks! it Worked.. Thumbs up to you \m/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the generic `onClick` then you could run into future issues with other elements click handlers in your app. I would add `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` to each `CheckBox` in your xml file. Then add the method I show below, customized to your id's etc.

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkBx1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Option 1"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkBx2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Option 2"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkBx3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Option 3"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

Main Activity:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View v) {
    CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBx1);
    CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBx2);
    CheckBox chk3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBx3);

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.chkBx1:
        if (chk1.isChecked()) {
            chk2.setEnabled(false);
            chk3.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            chk1.setEnabled(true);
            chk2.setEnabled(true);
            chk3.setEnabled(true);
        }
        break;

    case R.id.chkBx2:
        if (chk2.isChecked()) {
            chk1.setEnabled(false);
            chk3.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            chk1.setEnabled(true);
            chk2.setEnabled(true);
            chk3.setEnabled(true);
        }
        break;

    case R.id.chkBx3:
        if (chk3.isChecked()) {
            chk1.setEnabled(false);
            chk2.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            chk1.setEnabled(true);
            chk2.setEnabled(true);
            chk3.setEnabled(true);
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use radio buttons and make them look like check boxes by changing button property

```
 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/chkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    andriod:button="@drawable/youcheckboximage"
    />
```